# How to check which dynamically created radio button is selected on clicking submit button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

> I know this question has been asked plenty of times before, but I haven't been able to find a solution that works for my specific case.
>
> So I have a radio button which I create statically initially. The HTML code is given below

```
    <body>
        <div class = 'container'>
            <div class = 'row'>
                <div class = 'col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 well'>
                    <div class = 'col-md-4'>
                        <h1>Title Placeholder</h1>
                        <p>My vote goes to</p>
```

> In the below div is where I create the first static radio button

```
                        <div class = 'radio'>
                            <label>
                                <input type = 'radio' value = '1' name = 'options' class = 'radio-options'/>
                                <p id = 'radio1'>The value of 1</p>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <button type = 'submit' class = 'btn btn-primary submit-butt'>Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>   

    </body>
```

> Below is the section of the javascript file where I create dynamic radio buttons

```
function createOptions(length, options){
    $('#radio1').html(options[0]);
    for (var i = 1; i < length; i++){
        $('.radio').append('<br>');
        $('.radio').append('<label><input type = radio value = 1 name = options class = radio-options/><p>'+options[i]+'</p></label>');
    }
    $('.radio').append('<br>');
    $('.radio').append('<label><input type = radio value = 1 name = options class = radio-options/><p>Custom</p></label>')
}
```

> Now, when I click the submit button, with one of the radio buttons checked, I want to be able to know which of the radio buttons is checked and also the p value contained within its input tags

```
$('.submit-butt').on('click', function(){
                   if($('.radio-options').is(':checked')){
                       console.log('I have my value');
                   } 
                });
```

> I tried the above code, but it only seems to work for the first statically created radio button. How do I get this same functionality to work for all the radio buttons, both statically and dynamically generated?

Answer (score 1):

as long as your form is only deal with one set of radio buttons you can do it this way just change formId to whatever class/id you are using for the form wrapping the radios.

`$('input[name=radioName]:checked', '#formId').val()`

```
$('.submit-butt').on('click', function(){
   var selectedRadioValue = $('input[name=radioName]:checked','#formId').val()
   console.log(selectedRadioValue)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this is how you can do it. refer the working demo.

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<title></title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
#dynamicradio{
    margin-left: 100px;
}

#clickme{
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-top:10px;
}

</style>

<body>

<div id="dynamicradio"></div>
<input type="button" value="submit" id="clickme">

</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
// here we create the dynamic radio button.
var create_dynamic_radio = $("<input type='radio' id='myradioo'> <label> My Radio Button</label>")
$("#dynamicradio").append(create_dynamic_radio);

// here we write the code for click function.
$("#clickme").click(function(){
    var isradiochecked = $("#myradioo").prop('checked');//check whether the dynamic radio button is checked or not.
    if(isradiochecked == true)
    {
        alert("dynamic radio button is checked");
    }
    else
    {
        alert("dynamic radio button isn't checked");
    }
});

</script>

</html>
```

Comment: "try this" is no help to anybody. What has changed? Why does it work?

Comment: @AnuradhS Is it necessary to create the dynamic radio button through a variable? Also, is it necessary to create the new dynamic radio buttons as part of a separate div tag?

Comment: It is not necessary, if you want you can create it without a variable.